# Using a junction object relationship as criteria for a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, query, junction-object

I have a requirement to run an automatic accounts payable flow that requires a public group to enroll an account (we have 89 public groups)

An example would be

- Public group A has Invoice Z with Account Y. Invoice Z is overdue and Public Group A would like a flow to run to followup every two weeks.

  - For the flow to run, Public Group A must have enrolled Account Y into the flow by using a screenflow to form a relationship to a junction object that controls the relationship for this flow.
- If that public group is not related to that account, do not run the flow.
- *Note* Account security is private and shared using sharing rules.

My questions are:

- How might I best query if a relationship has been established between Public Group -> Account in a flow?
- Is a junction object the best way to manage this type of relationship? The requirement exists because each public group must manage their own enrollments and disenrollments.

Would very, very much appreciate the help

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to clarify what you asking.  Groups cannot "have" or own accounts directly.  Do you mean that that the account owner is a Group A?  Or do you mean that the account is shared to Group A?

Comment: I mean the account is shared to Group A. I would like to form a relationship between public groups and accounts wherein I can control the invoice flow based on whether or not that relationship exists. Hence why I though a junction object might work.